# What is another way of saying "final solution?"

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

"[Final Solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Solution)" is not the optimal phrase to use because it has a negative historical reference.

When working on a project, I'd like to find a phrase that describes the process of evolving solutions (see, for example, [Agile software development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development)).

Additionally, the phrase should fit well with phrases like initial solution, intermediate solution, etc.

**Update**: Doesn't necessarily have to be a 'solution.'

Comment: Forget solution and call it an "iteration"? Our "most recent iteration" has features X, Y and Z and fixes bugs 1, 2 and 3. Or "version". Nothing in software is ever final unless you're out of business, so the word "final" here seems to be the most problematic.

Comment: It's not actually for software, I just wanted to take the concept of an evolving solution.

Comment: In the context of evolving solutions, the word "final" has no place - it states that there will be no more versions, and that this has no bugs and it has everything anyone will ever want.  This is *never the case*.  You would really call it "V 1.0" meaning *"the first version which was released to the public"*.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I have an issue with the phrase "final solution" due to the connotation to the holocaust, so it was nice to see other options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me self-answer with **final product**. Even though the solution may not be a product, the phrase best describes the iterative and evolving process.

Comment: or "final version"

Comment: In the end, 'final' product' is the most useful and is my replacement for 'final solution'. Thanks for all the great answers!

Answer (score 6):

"Logical Conclusion" is similar to "Final Solution" and virtually devoid of connotation.

Also you may consider coining a neologism, perhaps something seemingly-contradictory, paradoxical or oxymoronic -- perhaps *everconclusion* or *endorand* (poor example practically, but interesting - combines the words "end" "or" and "and" as to suggest the (end) implies the inevitable connection of (or) the next thing (and)).

Comment: Have a vote for creativity!

Comment: You had me at Logical Conclusion

Comment: Don't make up words where perfectly good words already exist.

Comment: thank you, @DavidRicherby gives really important advice here. My suggesting making up a word resulted from that I took the original question to possibly involve an attempt to come up with a name for a company/project. But if that's not the case, there is probably not a single good reason to make up words as in alternative to seeking out and using those already in existence.

Answer (score 6):

[Optimal solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem#Combinatorial_optimization_problem) gets tossed around a lot these days when one is iterating one's way towards the best possible answer.

Comment: probably the best so far.

Comment: This implies that you actually found the best possible solution. Pretty different from "the solution I ended up using".

Comment: @CodesInChaos In solution space, there are local optima and global optima. It's not uncommon, or even wrong, to use the term optimal solution on what is in fact merely a local optima. In part, that's true because whatever solution you implement must lie within the region of the feasible http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region, which is often far smaller than the entire solution space.

Comment: One issue with 'optimal solution' is that it doesn't guarantee it's the last.

Answer (score 4):

I have no canonical answers, nothing much to back me, but in the situation I would say:

> ***the** solution*,

which I'm sure will speak a lot without much ado.

Answer (score 3):

How about **final result**? This is also used in other contexts, but I think it also fits into your software development example.

Comment: or "end result."

Answer (score 2):

I think "ultimate solution" fits in well with your series of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Although in connection with Agile software development the term: "eventual iteration" describes the best way what's going on, I would propose "definitive" as emphasizing the result and not the process how to obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize an answer has already been selected, but consider

**finalized** ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/finalized))

> Put into final form; complete

as in **Finalized Product**.

This has the connotation that a conscious decision was made to call this iteration the final form.

Answer (score 1):

How about 
**complete solution**
or
**end solution**?

Comment: Ironically, *end solution* comes even closer to a literal translation of the German *Endlösung.*

Answer (score 1):

You say the answer doesn't have to be of the form "       solution" but why not go the other way around?

At the moment, you have a series of solutions: solution 1, solution 2, ..., solution *n*.  You could refer to solution *n* as just "the solution" and solutions 1 through *n-1* as "intermediate stages", "solution stages", "intermediate solutions" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Eventual solution. I think this phrase fits in well with the idea of a process working towards something, but doesn't necessarily imply perfection.