# Is the phrase “final solution” used in the field of software development?

Tags: phrase-usage

I recently came across the phrase “final solution” being used in communication between software developers. It was used like this:

> I was working on fixing the issue with the data. I tried several potential solutions, but they did not work or had other drawbacks. The final solution I found was X. I implemented it and the data loads correctly now."

While the phrase was used purely in a technical context, I still found it shocking, and I was not expecting to see the two words put together like this. But maybe it’s just me…

I came across [What is another way of saying "final solution?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153377/what-is-another-way-of-saying-final-solution), where the asker was searching for an alternative phrase to “final solution”, even in a technical context, because of its negative connotations.

I would like to know if this phrase is commonplace in technical communication.

**Are there any instances of this particular phrase in technical publications or communication from international tech corporations?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126252/discussion-on-question-by-hb20007-is-the-phrase-final-solution-used-in-the-fie).

Comment: Recently, the song "Baby, It's Cold Outside" has been deemed problematic. That does not mean that no one can use that phrase anymore, and indeed [other songs with that name already exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_It%27s_Cold_Outside_(Pezband_song)). *Final solution* is used a lot. **The** Final Solution, is not.

Comment: It is as evident as the fact that no one mistake nuclear holocaust for **The** Holocaust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***the final solution***](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/final-solution-in-depth)

On this site, most of the users are older and more educated than much of the general population, so without a doubt this usage will find resistance because of its association with the [Holocaust.](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/final-solution-in-depth)

By way of  contrast, it appears that [most Millennials and Gen Z are either unaware or only tangentially aware of the Holocaust](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/survey-finds-shocking-lack-holocaust-knowledge-among-millennials-gen-z-n1240031) and all that entails.
Most recent 10th grade Western students  have read " [Diary of Anne Frank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Diary_of_a_Young_Girl)", but consider it to be a "novel assigned as required reading" which they did in [SparkNotes](https://www.sparknotes.com/) to cover a few questions in Literature .  That's scary.

So does it occur in the techno-babble of the software dev world...

**I think most of the recent usages you will find [(and there are many)](https://www.google.com/search?q=final%20solution%20programming&tbm=bks&ei=CBvAYPqvKe6qggefzo3wDA&oq=final%20solution%20programming&gs_l=psy-ab.3...7007.7940.0.8369.4.4.0.0.0.0.175.287.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.1.175...33i10k1.0.qLEm_emSmus) will come from people who belong to younger  generations, or a country which has  only scanty History courses about the WWII on the European stage.***

As it has been said..."Those who ignore history are doomed to repeat it."

---

*Sidebar:

Many of the world's finest coders come from Asia, and some usages *may seem* tone-deaf...

...but most Westerners tend to forget that the war had a huge impact on the people of Asia (especially China, Vietnam, Burma, and Korea) and the Middle East, and that the indigenous peoples  faced abuse at the hand's of the Imperialist-style forms of  local government which was not dissimilar to the  NAZI treatment of the so-called "mongrel races". Family history tends to focus on local traumas, so it is no wonder that far-off events are not well-remembered.

As a personal  example, like  many Americans of my generation I grew up listening to the stories of family members such as  my great-uncle "Lefty" told about about Patton's Third Army,  and was convinced that the Western Allies won WWII and freed the concentration camp  inmates, when actually it was the Soviets that entered Berlin first and took control of  the Chancellery grounds... it was a [Soviet scout](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2015/01/27/what-a-soviet-soldier-saw-when-his-unit-liberated-auschwitz-70-years-ago/)  of the 322nd Rifle Division that first liberated an extermination camp in Poland called Auschwitz ...

Comment: Helpful and perceptive analysis of the context in which such questions must be viewed.

Comment: I think this answer is true for Western countries. In countries which were not so involved in WWII, young people probably wouldn't have even read Anne Frank's diary.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the best answer. While it does not provide detailed evidence that this phrase is used in this context (see the answer I wrote for that), it does provide a Google link. But more importantly, after establishing that the phrase is actually used, this answer explains why we should try to give the benefit of the doubt if the phrase was used in a technical context by people who are less educated about WWII.

Comment: I mean, I'm a 33 year old American software developer, and I would not find the use of that phrase unusual at all in describing the end result of a problem-solving process. If anything, it's a little formal sounding and I might use other language casually, but I'd be surprised if I never uttered it before or if I'd never heard others do so. I know "anecdote" is not the singular form of "data", but I have a hard time believing anybody consciously avoids using these words like this in software development nowadays.

Comment: I think you'll find a stark contrast between *final solution* and **The** *Final Solution*.

Comment: One wonders what you'd make of "nuclear holocaust."

Comment: @GArthurBrown I’m not sure where you are going with this...or why.

My father was one of 400,000 service people that the US Government tested the first H-bombs on in the Nevada desert during the mid 1950s. His early death was possibly due to that.

Comment: [cont]
I grew up during the peak years of the cold war, and some of my most vivid grade school memories are of 'duck and cover' drills (basically ‘bend over and kiss your ass goodbye’)...later in the early 70s, I was a nuclear specialist in the USN, and nuclear holocaust was something I lived with every day.  So for me, the phrase 'nuclear holocaust' is possibly a little more personal than it probably  is for you. @GArthurBrown

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure you can find an occasional example of someone putting the two words together in a neutral fashion, but I would suggest that **the phrase "final solution" is so closely tied to the Nazi plan to exterminate Jews in World War II that English speakers tend to avoid the combination, even when it would otherwise naturally occur**.

Evidence:

Both [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/final%20solution) and [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/final-solution) have only a single definition for "final solution":

> the Nazi program for extermination of all Jews in Europe

> the Nazi program of annihilating the Jews of Europe during the Third Reich.

Answer (score 6):

After further research, and a useful comment by Jim which as now been moved to chat, I believe I can answer my own question.

The phrase **does** seem to be in use in the context of software development or other technical fields.

I am **not** saying that it is a good idea to use this phrase in a multicultural environment, neither am I commenting on the philosophical issue of whether there does or does not exist a “final solution” to a technical problem. I am just providing evidence that it does seem to be in use.

### Evidence

A paper titled [Artificial Intelligence for Software Engineering: An Initial Review on Software Bug Detection and Prevention](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347739598_Artificial_Intelligence_for_Software_Engineering_An_Initial_Review_on_Software_Bug_Detection_and_Prediction), which seems to have been published in a scientific journal, contains the following text:

> A final solution should include a combination of both knowledge types to provide efficient and reliable software.

However, it is worth noting that the authors seem to have an East Asian background, and I am not sure if the specific scientific journal is reputable internationally.

---

I was able to find the phrase in another paper titled [How Bad Can a Bug Get? An Empirical Analysis of Software Failures in the OpenStack Cloud Computing Platform](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.04055.pdf):

> the problem report also includes a final solution shipped in OpenStack

This is a preprint so I am not sure if the paper got published with this wording.

---

Another example is from [Developer recommendation on bug commenting:
a ranking approach for the developer crowd](http://scis.scichina.com/en/2017/072105.pdf)
:

> These selected developers are ranked according to their combined scores as the final solution.

This paper has been published in some scientific journal, however, I was unable to determine the name or the reputability of the journal.

---

I found a paper where the term was used in the title: [Mapping Problem and Requirements to Final Solution: A Document Analysis of Capstone Design Projects](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255568399_Mapping_Problem_and_Requirements_to_Final_Solution_A_Document_Analysis_of_Capstone_Design_Projects). This paper, at the time of writing, was cited 7 times and [seems to have been presented at a reputable conference](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/IDETC-CIE/proceedings-abstract/IDETC-CIE2011/54846/569/351829). This is the strongest evidence by far.

---

A book published by Salem Press and titled [USA in Space](https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/USA_in_Space/XmJFAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22final+solution+was+to%22&dq=%22final+solution+was+to%22&printsec=frontcover) also includes the phrase:

> The final solution was to modify NASA’s Gemini craft…

---

Finally, another book titled [Professional JavaScript For Web Developers](https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/Professional_JavaScript_for_Web_Develope/5pr15F4JbCUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22final+solution+was+to%22&pg=PA20&printsec=frontcover), published by Wiley, also uses the phrase:

> The final solution was the enclose the script code in an HTML comment.

---

I also found a question on StackOverflow Meta where some people have posted useful information: [Can the expression “final solution” be used on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401489/can-the-expression-final-solution-be-used-on-the-site)

Comment: The research presented in this answer is useful, relevant and should help answer the question. I therefore cannot understand why it has been downvoted; I have removed the downvote.

Comment: @Anton You "removed the downvote"? What does that even mean? Can mods remove *other* people's downvotes?? I firmly stand by my downvote, and I'd like it back if you please. This is a purportedly "well-researched" answer to a mind-bogglingly wrong-headed question. Have some people, while discussing their last iteration of several possible solutions, dropped the phrase "final solution"? Yes, of course. Is it commonly or routinely used? No, and this answer doesn't offer evidence that it is. *Should* it be used? No, not if we can avoid it.

Comment: @BradC My apologies for incorrect terminology on my part. I do not have such a privilege and would be loth to use it it if I did. I have only "removed" in the sense of upvoting. Your downvote of course is still there and has not been affected.

Answer (score 3):

It’s dangerous to use.

In software development it may come up without bad intent. “To solve problem X, we first tried solution A which failed because… solution B worked better but was too slow. Our final solution was to combine A and B.”

Even though it is intended to have no darker meaning, I would definitely change the wording because it will cause offense - to normal people and to people who want to be offended. For example “The solution that we finally chose was to combine A and B”.

PS. The original German term is one word. And that one word can never, ever be used except for a plan to kill millions of people.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a technical document written in English which uses the phrase “final solution” several times, including in the title. I showed it to my religious Jewish colleague who has been in the IT industry for 15+ years.

The document is related to a security issue which was fixed with temporary workarounds in the past and now should be fixed the proper way.

My colleague had some comments on the technical details and was completely oblivious to the phrase “final solution”. It seems that the association of the phrase with the Holocaust just did not cross his mind at all.

---

I think the best approach is to avoid using this phrase in your own speech and writing, and simply use one of the alternatives mentioned here: [What is another way of saying "final solution?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153377/what-is-another-way-of-saying-final-solution)

However, if you come across the phrase in a technical context, it is logical to assume that the author did not think about it and did not intend to be offensive.